# Is it possible to build a ordering application using Opencart API

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I would like to build a third party application which is used to make orders from the my opencart store.My opencart store is using version 2.2 and I planned to build this app using OPENCART API.

### The features this third party app consist of

1. able to autosugges the products from the opencart store and add the
   selected product to a table
2. after adding all products, We can submit the order and the the order will also automatically completed
3. the delevery method is set to "collect from store"
4. payment method is set to "Cash ON delivery"
5. after the order has been completed the stock should be deduct from the opencart store.

I would like to know is it possible to build this third party application? Also I would like to hear guides on how to do this . 
You are ideas are appreciated very much

Comment: Yes this is very much possible. You will have to require extensive knowledge of opencart in order to do so.

Comment: You mean A POS like application which connected to opencart store is Possible right? 
Do you have any example stuffs which would be helpful for me to move on with developing this

Comment: You need to create an API either with opencart or any other cms.